# Same code rendering two different matrices

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm trying to type this on mSE
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_3 \\
x_3  \\ 
x_4\\
\end{pmatrix}, is rendering like this for me
[image]

what to do?

Comment: Check out the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference section on Matrices](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023).  Your first "column" expression is MathJax, while your second expression is just an image.  The last image is badly cutoff.  I'm unclear what you found difficult about typing a row matrix (the separator for row entries is an ampersand, if that is what you needed to know).

Comment: I typed the exact same code on MSE, and this is what I got. Tha's the issue

Comment: It looks like you are not using MathJax correctly, which is why I referred you to the basic tutorial post about such things.  Would it help if I wrote out the correct syntax for a column matrix and a row matrix?  Or can you link to a post on Math.SE where you had this problem?

Comment: Occasionally problems with MathJax can be traced to an unconventional use of `\newcommand` or `\def` somewhere else on a page, see e.g. [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17477/unusual-behavior-of-in-pmatrix-environment).  I don't suspect that is your difficulty, but having a link to the page  where you tried to "type this on mSE" would help to diagnose what is going wrong.

Comment: I see, thanks. As for linking to the post, I didn't post it because of the problem I faced

Comment: If the screenshot is from the post preview (i.e. while you were composing the post), then I think I have also experienced this sometimes. Adding four backslashes instead of two fixes the display in the preview in such cases. But even if I don't do that, it ends up looking fine after submitting the post.

Comment: Here is an old discussion mentioning this: [Willie Wong's answer to 'Using the align environment?'](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3526/915354). I don't know why this issue sometimes (very rarely) recurs for me; I've just assumed that it is due to a poor internet connection. Perhaps your issue is the same...

Answer (score 1):

To sum up what's been mentioned in comments:

If you use the `\\` separator in the pmatrix block you get
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_3 \\ x_3  \\ x_4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
and if you use the `&` separator you get
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_3 & x_3 & x_4
\end{pmatrix}
and if you use them both you can get
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_3 & x_3 & x_4 \\
x_1 & x_3 & x_3 & x_4
\end{pmatrix}